# Kids movie came out in 90s with wrist watch set alarm for wrestling show but by end is used in another time period

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have been trying to find the title of this kid's movie involving these 2 scenes and the best description from what I can remember. Each of the scenes are connected by the use of the watch but in two different time periods in 1980s/1990s and then in the past.

First it’s about two best friends (I think both are male) who both set their wrist watches at a certain time to remember to watch a TV show (I think wrestling?) each week and after confirming the exact times on their wrist watches they say yeah air alright and possibly high five.

The show somehow had to do with time travel to the past. Only one of the friends goes back but I'm not sure how. While being stuck in the past and trying to solve a problem to help the people in the past, his alarm for the TV show goes off and he remembers the title of the TV show by hearing the alarm uses the battery to solve the problem. The watch didn’t cause the time traveling only that the battery of the watch was used in the past after traveling there.

But other then those scenes I don’t know the whole main plot and around the time it came out in the early 90s or late 80s.

It's not *A Kid In King Arthur’s Court*.

Comment: Do I get it right that the boy travels to a kind of medieval epoch? Do you remember other epochs as well?

Comment: Maybe? All I can be sure if it has that scene about each friend getting excited about the tv show that their watch is set for. Then some how uses when in the past. But haven’t been able to find it. Thanks for everyone in the continued search of the movie name.

Comment: I seem to recognize this and think I remember that the show is American Gladiators, but I can remember nothing else. Does that sound correct?

Comment: This guy has a list of 600 Time Travel related movies, https://www.imdb.com/list/ls058641508/ might be worth a look. I didn't see one that matched, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### I think this is ***[The Amazing Panda Adventure.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112342/)***

I found this based on Tashus' comment that the show the kids set their alarms to watch was American Gladiators. IMDB has a "Connections" page for American Gladiators that lists references to that show in other media. For *The Amazing Panda Adventure,* [it says this:](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096532/movieconnections)

> Ryan and his friend Johnny look on their watches and call "American Gladiators!" to watch this series on TV - later when Ryan and Ling are in the river Ryan's watch bleeps and he calls this series again

The protagonist Ryan's father works with pandas in China, and Ryan comes along with him on one of the trips. During the trip, a panda cub is taken by poachers, and Ryan and a local girl/translator named Ling go on an adventure to rescue the cub and return it to its mother. The plot summary on IMDB doesn't mention the scene you remember where Ryan uses the watch battery to solve a problem, but [Wikipedia does:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Panda_Adventure)

> Ryan realizes that he can use the batteries in his watch to power the radio collar and enable his father to locate them.

The movie was released in 1995. The only thing that doesn't fit your description is that there's no time travel, but most of the movie takes place in rural China, so there is at least an element of travel to a place with limited technology.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy! This is one solid first answer!

Comment: This matches the new description pretty well

Comment: Yes! Way to go Tashus and shmeeku ! For over 10 years or more only could remember close descriptions of 2 scenes.

Comment: Yes! It’s “ The Amazing Panda Adventure”  Way to go Tashus and shmeeku ! For over 10 years or more only could remember close descriptions of 2 scenes. Then try searching on yahoo or google search engines and not coming close. First answer of from Tashus of the watch alarm to show of “American Gladiators” then shmeeku with the finishing touch of finding the movie THANK YOU So MUCH ! Been very frustrating racking my brain and just thought with using the watch batteries was time travel related because I love watching those and in the 90s a lot of different kids movies were out. Awesome finally it

Answer (score 6):

Could this be **[Clockstoppers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0157472/)**?

The plot summary mentions the **watch**:

> Until now, Zak Gibbs' greatest challenge has been finding a way to buy a car. But when he discovers an **odd wristwatch** amidst his father's various inventions and slips it on, something very strange happens. **The world around him seemingly comes to a stop**; giving the effect that everyone has come to a stop. Zak quickly learns how to manipulate the device, and **he and his quick-witted, beautiful new friend, Francesca, have some real fun**. What they soon realize, though, is they are not alone in hypertime.

It came out in 2002, so pretty close to your guesstimate. It also has two *main* characters, who are both young adults, and only one has the watch. I don't believe they can time *travel* in the movie, but they can stop it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yea kind of but it has more a 90s feel. I think both are male friends. Also clockstoppers is slowing down time but thanks though. But the watch didn’t cause time traveling only that the battery of the watch was used in the past. Which was used by both friends that had a alarm that set for both friends to watch a specific tv show.